# How to read tables written in a file on lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make an API for the computercraft mod that you can give an item name and it'll look up a dictionary and craft the item for you. While I have gotten it to craft the item after you give it the array. I am having trouble with a way to upload the recipes from a separate file.

I have a few files that each has a bunch of 2-dimensional tables that I want another program to import, one table per line. so basically

file1

```
itemA = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}}
itemB = {{"j","k","l"},{"m","n","o"},{"p","q","r"}}
```

file2

```
itemA = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}}
itemC = {{"j","k","l"},{"m","n","o"},{"p","q","r"}}
```

What I want is when I read this by line you get a table structure that is basically

```
recipies = {itemA = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}}, itemB = {{"j","k","l"},{"m","n","o"},{"p","q","r"}}}
```

There also needs to be an identical recipe check in case if multiple dictionaries carry the same recipe for the same item

I don't have much experience with string manipulation in any language, But I don't know how to remotely get around this in Lua.

Comment: I think I missed something. In your expected result, where did `itemC` go? Do you just want to combine several files dictionaries into one large one, without duplicates? Can you change the format of your files, e.g. instead of global `itemA` putting them into a table, then returning the entire table?

Comment: basically itemA would be the name of a certain item I want to craft, example would be minecraft:torch, or minecraft:crafting_table. I want duplication detection because Each file will represent a diffrent mod. so vanilla is the base game, computetercraft is the recipies added through the computercraft mod. ect

Comment: Are you trying to upload it to a turtle? Is the file already in a turtle and you just want to grab the recipe from the file? like example `turtleCraft(recipes.BoneMeal)`?

Comment: Well I want to have a method that grabs the whole dictionary, but yes. That Is what I'm going for

Answer (score 1):

So this should be a pretty good solution. Simply you just want to open the txt file and unserialize it. This turns it from a string back into a table which can then be indexed

With `fs.open()` you are opening the file for a set purpose. The `"r"` is saying that is is being opened for reading only. [Here](https://computercraft.info/wiki/Fs.open) are some of the other options that can be used depening on what you want to do

```
-- Open the text file which currently has all of the recipes in a table
local recipes = textutils.unserialize(fs.open("recipes.txt", "r"))

-- We use textutils.unserialize() to change the text from a string to a table

local running = true

-- Setup an infinite loop
while running do
    io.write("Enter a recipe name to craft or type 'EXIT' to exit\n")

    -- Getting the user input
    choice = io.read()

    -- If the user types 'EXIT' then stop the program
    if choice == "EXIT" then
        break
    end

    -- Craft the recipe
    turtleCraft(recipe.ItemA)
end
```

Some others seem to be talking about security but if this is being used for ComputerCraft it really is no issue at all. Are you using a crafty turtle and the craft command or how are you achieving crafting via a table?

I also should add the tables would be setup like this

```
{
    itemA = {
        {"a","b","c"},
        {"d","e","f"},
        {"g","h","i"}
    },
    itemB = {
        {"j","k","l"},
        {"m","n","o"},
        {"p","q","r"}
    }
}
```

Of course the format does not overly matter but the keyword `recipes` would not be in there.

https://computercraft.info/wiki/Fs.list

This link may also be found useful, it demonstrates a way to loop through each file in a directory. I don't currently have a way to test it though.

I have been messing around with ComputerCraft a lot lately. Make sure to tag your question questions and future with the `ComputerCraft` tag to make them easier to see by people looking to directly answer ComputerCraft based lua questions